# Scripting Python to show Megabits/second in Real Time

Tags: python, linux

It works well but I need to transform the download/upload data in Megabits per second in real time. Please see my code below.

```
import subprocess
def check_speed():
    '''Checking Server Upload and Download Speeds...'''
    _commandf = subprocess.Popen(['cat', '/proc/net/dev'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    _commands = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'eth0'], stdin=_commandf.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    _commandt = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '{ print $1 " " $9 }'], stdin=_commands.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    (_salida, err) = _commandt.communicate()
    _salida = _salida.split('\n')
    lista = ['Received Bytes: ', 'Transfered bytes: ']
    s = _salida[0].split(',')
    s = str(s)
    s = s.strip('[]')
    s = s.strip("''")
    s = s.strip('eth0:')
    l = s.split()
    print lista[0] + l[0]
    print lista[1] + l[1]
if __name__=='__main__':
    check_speed()
```

Please, I would really appreciate your help guys.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you use subprocess to call `cat`, `grep`, etc? That is Python not Bash scripting. It would be better if you take a look at the link by George.

Comment: My script works as it drops out the result in bytes but I would like to get the result in Megabits per second the right way

Comment: This is the result I get:

Comment: <pre>Received Bytes: 20959953680223
Transfered bytes: 28305720326134</pre>

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use the os module is because subprocess offers a higher-level interface than os and it seems to be really good for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal solution without error checking, assumes eth0 exists

```
[a.strip() for a in os.popen('cat /proc/net/dev |grep eth0').read().split(' ') if a!='']
```

This will give you a list like this

```
['eth0:379748344',
 '4185860',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0',
 '6284995641',
 '6185697',
 '0',
 '105',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0',
 '0']
```